# Copy folder content included in C# project to output directory without parent folder

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2013

I have included my project dependencies files to C# project from directory in my project with name "Dependencies" that include every file that project need to this project sub directory (because i don't want the project seems crowded and add needed file to "Dependencies" sub directory) but i don't want the sub directory copied to output path. I want only content of sub directory with all structure copied to output path. I don't want use post built Copy command because i have unneeded files and folders that i don't want copied to output directory. Is there any way to do this?[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) "jobs" for this, which allows to save a job description file which tells robocopy what to include and where to copy. So my Post-Build Event would be along the lines of

```
robocopy $(ProjectDir)\dependencies $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir) /JOB:$(ProjectDir)\dependencies\publish
```

The job file is then called publish.rcj and also placed in the dep. directory

Another way of doing it is to create a setupproject that gathers the resources you need, but that is even more work :-)

Here goes. ROBOCOPY

```
robocopy /?
```

gives you the help you need to figure it out :)
Here is one to get you started:

```
robocopy c:\source c:\target /S /E /XD systems /XF publish.rcj /NP /NJS /NJH /NFL /NDL /SAVE:publish.rcj
```

Explanation of some settings:

- **/SAVE:publish.rcj** tells it to save the job description to file (named) publish.rcj
- **/XD systems** tells it to ignore folder named systems from copying (you can list many)
- **/XF publish.rcj** tells it to not copy files named publish.rcj (you can list many)
- **/S /E** tells it to copy all subfolders even empty ones

  - /NP /NJH /NJS /NFL /NDL is just to turn off listing of files and folders that are copied (play with it to see)

Now a "trick" (can't seem to make this work correctly from command line):
Open the job file (publish.rcj) and substitute:

```
/SD:c:\Source With /NOSD
```

and

```
/DD:c:\Target With /NODD
```

- the NOSD (no source directory) and NODD (no destination dir.) tells the job to always get Source and target from input - the $(ProjectDir) stuff from the post build event

Now you can call the job like this:

```
robocopy c:\my_new_source c:\my_new_target /job:publish
```

And it will use all the paramteres specified in the job description file.

Comment: It seems complicated. Can you explain me have can i exclude some files and directories from copying with robocopy and how can i create a job file?  Thanks.

Comment: changed answer to include sample of usage of robocopy With job file